# Est-ce qu'on peut dire je te niaise? (I'm just teasing you)

Tags: québec

Bonjour,

Attention: usage québécois

Souvent, j'entends : je niaise pas (I'm not kidding)

Mais si je veux dire quelque chose comme (c'est une blague): Je te niaise

ou simplement : je niaise

Quelle est la forme correcte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D’après mon expérience, l’expression « Je te niaise » ou le verbe « Niaiser » est valide dans le jargon québecois. Tu risques d’être plus passe-partout en disant « J’te niase là » (*Là* étant une des particules grammaticales les plus utilisées au Québec, mais vraiment on fait juste rajouter des mots partout) ou même « Bin voyons don, j’te niase la! capote pas! » si ton interlocuteur est particulièrement offensé par ta blague/commentaire.

Les formes que tu as suggérées sont toutes bonnes pour le parler et à l’écrit.

Le verbe est dans le *Larousse*, donc tu peux peut-être utiliser le *Bescherelle* pour voir les différents temps de conjugaison, si ton but est de l’incorporer à l’écrit.